# Restore SQL Back ups back to server from Directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I have list of SQL databases taken as a backup and stored in D:\Backup\ drive, Task is to restore all backups, back to SQL Server.  Looking for stored procedure which will open each file from directory and  restore all files one by one to server.

```
Sample list of Databases

restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB1.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB2.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB3.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB4.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB5.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB6.bak' with replace
restore database master from disk='D:\BACKUP\DB7.bak' with replace
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to restore to the same server where the backups were taken or to a different Sql Server?

Comment: yes same server

Comment: There is no magic procedure that exists to do this for you, you'll need to roll your own bespoke solution for your needs. It's a complex process because each database backup requires a custom restore command for the various data files, log file and paths for each. See `msdb.dbo.backupset` for list of backups on the server. I've built custom solutions for this you'll need to use `restore filelistonly from disk` and some `dynamic sql` to iterate over a list of databases and build the appropriate `restore` command.

Comment: Do you have multiple `master` backup logs that you want to restore? Doesn't really make sense to keep restoring the same DB over and over. And restoring master is a complex operation that needs very specific steps, some of which are out of scope of SQL batches.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to look at the dbatools powershell module for this. For your needs:

```
$server = 'yourServer';

$backups = get-dbabackupinformation -SqlInstance $server -Path 'D:\BACKUP';
$backups | restore-dbadatabase -SqlInstance $server -withreplace;
```

Note - `restore-dbadatabase` has a bunch of options. The defaults are pretty good for most cases but see what's available.

---

But also! Two things grab my attention about your sample:

1. You're restoring the master database. That should only be done if something extraordinary happened (e.g. disk corruption, an admin or malicious actor trashed the server, etc).
2. You're restoring the same database from multiple different files without specifying `with norecovery`.

I'd guess that both of these are attributed to fast and loose with the sample code. But it's worth calling out as restoring master will have consequences for your server and restoring multiple files could make your restore take longer than it should (e.g. if each of those backups represents a daily backup, restoring only the one that represents your desired RPO makes sense).